# How to re-enabled Chrome developer console after a website disabled it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

Some website is disabling Chrome console(console.log is not working) on every page where it's widgets placed.

**Is it a way to re-enable it back?** (like hack or something)

P.S. As i understand, they are just rewriting console functions. So my question is basically this: is it any solution to rewrite it back to normal?(if my understanding of blocking console is correct)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hack you can use. I can't see any way to reset it to the original `Console` class that Chrome uses, e.g. `window.console = new Console()`, because it seems to be inaccessible.

Instead you need to get hold of a different `console` object and point the current `window.console` to that one. The easiest way to do that is to create a hidden iframe and use that one's. Note you have to keep the iframe on the page. If you remove it, the `console` will get cleaned up and stop working completely.

Here's a jQuery 1-liner to do it and [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjcn4qjz/2/):

```
window.console =
    $('<iframe src="about:blank" style="display:none;"/>')
    .appendTo(document.body)[0].contentWindow.console;
```

And if you want a pure JS solution ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjcn4qjz/1/)):

```
var theFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
theFrame.src = "about:blank";
theFrame.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(theFrame);
window.console = theFrame.contentWindow.console;
```

---

The only other thing to note with this is if the current page itself is in an iframe with [`sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox)ing, as stack snippets are, then you may get Security Errors and there's not a lot you can do about it.

This snippet [currently] doesn't run for example because it only has `sandbox="allow-scripts"`

```js
// break the console
window.console = {
  log: function(x) { alert('haha I hijacked your console'); }
}

console.log('debug message');

var theFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
theFrame.src = "about:blank";
theFrame.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(theFrame);
window.console = theFrame.contentWindow.console;

console.log('debug message');
```

Answer (score 0):

You said "re-enable". I'm not sure how to do that. On the other hand you could prevent it from being overridden in the first place if you control the page. Just make sure this gets executed first.

```
(function(origConsole) {
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'console', { 
    get: function() { return origConsole; }, 
    set: function() {}, 
    enumerable: true, 
    configurable: false, 
  });
}(window.console));
(function(origLog) {
  Object.defineProperty(window.console, 'log', { 
    get: function() { return origLog; }, 
    set: function() {}, 
    enumerable: true, 
    configurable: false, 
  });
}(window.console.log.bind(window.console)));
```

Maybe even inject it using an extension